# Accessing packages in Java

Tags: java

I set the String message in ReadSource class, and I want access it in Driver class from Automotive class methods, but it displays null and not the message. I have tried to print the message in Automotive setName(String) and it displays the correct String, yet I cant acces it in my main class.

My problem can be illustrate by testing my code below.

Can someone help me or explain it ? Thank you very much.

```
package Driver;

import Util.ReadSource;
import Model.Automotive;
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Automotive auto = new Automotive();
        ReadSource read =  new ReadSource();

        String main = "Message";
        //set the message and display
        read.set(main);

        //get the message that was set in the read.set(String)
        auto.getMessage();
    }

}
package Util;

import Model.Automotive;
public class ReadSource {


    public void set(String message){
        Automotive auto = new Automotive();
        System.out.println("This messasge is in getMessage in the
  class ReadSource "+ message);
        //Set the name for automotive
        auto.setName(message);
    }
}
//This the the ouput
/*This messasge is in getMessage in the class ReadSource Message
Message is Message
This messasge is in getMessage in the class Automotive null*/
```

Comment: So, where's the code? Just paste the relevant code and error message.

Comment: You are creating two *different* `Automotive` objects. Why would you expect setting a value on one of them would be reflected by the other? That would defeat the entire purpose of creating multiple objects, don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Driver {
public static void main(String args[]){

    Automotive auto = new Automotive();
    ReadSource read =  new ReadSource(auto);

    String main = "Message";
    //set the message and display
    read.set(main);

    //get the message that was set in the read.set(String)
    auto.getMessage();

    System.out.println(auto.getMessage());
}

public class ReadSource {

Automotive auto;

public ReadSource(Automotive auto) {
    this.auto = auto;
}

public void set(String message) {

    System.out.println("This messasge is in getMessage in the  class ReadSource: " + message);
    //Set the name for automotive
    auto.setName(message);
}
```

}

```
public class Automotive {

String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return name;
}
```

}

Comment: Sir Abdul, You don't how much you help me, Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

In your ReadSource.set() method. You are creating a new instance of Automotive. Then passing the value of message through the set method *again* after creating a new instance of Automotive (which is never used again). What you want to do is to make a variable, (technically a *field* by definition) in the beginning of the class body.

```
public class ReadSource {
     private String message;

     public void setMessage(String message) {
         this.message = message;
     }

     // make a getter to return it somewhere else
}
```

Now the message can be accessed in the main class with auto.getMessage(), (or something similar).

Then if in main you were to:

```
System.out.println(auto.getMessage());
```

It would print whatever was passed into the setMessage() method.